# cant get the array to my actionresult

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

im trying to get the values of all the checked checkboxes and post those values(integer) to an action result, the problem is i get an empty array at the controller side ...
my jquery code is as follow:

```
 function getIds() {

        var idList = new Array();
        var loopCounter = 0;
        //find all the checked checkboxes
        $("input:checked").each
    (
      function() {

          //fill the array with the values
          idList[loopCounter] = $(this).val();
          loopCounter += 1;
      }
    );
      //Send the list off
      alert(idList);
      var postData = { values: idList };    

      $.post("/Admin/Delete/", postData);
    }
```

my controller side code is following

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Delete(Int32[] values)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add delete logic here

                return RedirectToAction("NewSubDashboard");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

there is no problem with the posting but im gettin an empty array at the controller side...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i extracted the values from httpcontext as

HttpContext ctx = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
        string[] ValArr = ctx.Request.Params.GetValues(0);

Comment: What was the name of the parameter? If you use that name as the parameter name of the action, you don't need the above code.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't your `$.post` be:

```
$.post("/Admin/Delete/", postData);
```

Since `postData:idList` is probably undefined.

Comment: sry it was just a typo it not workin with 
$.post("/Admin/Delete/", postData);

Comment: @3nigma - have you debugged through to see what is actually posted and where in the `HttpContext` it is?

Comment: all i get at the controller is an empty array, i have added a debug point at the start of action result... did i  answer ur question :(

Comment: @3nigma - not really. Use Firebug to see if the `post` actually has the data. Then in your controller when the breakpoint is set, drill down till you can find the HttpContext and see if the data is there (assuming it was posted).

Comment: when i post the data and the debugger is hit i inspectthe page through firebug but i cant fint the post element...i have added a screen shot

Comment: @3nigma - Do this with the `net` tab open and enabled. The request and response should be there, with the data transferred.

Comment: @oded yes i think the data is posted its being shown in the firebug... but i didnt get at the controller end ... i am adding a screen shot of POST i which the "values[] 68" is showing...

Comment: the pic is not being uploaded :(